# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{3}{x^{4n}}+1)^\frac{1}{n},|x|<1,n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, limits

The limit is equal to $1$. I don't understand how.
If $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $|x|<1$, for example if $x=0.5$ we have
$$\frac{3}{0.5^\infty}$$ which I think should be $\infty$?

Comment: No, you would have "$(3/0.5^\infty+1)^0$".

Comment: @Alberto Debernardi Then how is the limit is $1$?

Comment: You actually cannot evaluate that, so you will have to apply some test or make some manipulations to the expression in order to be able to continue. Typically those examples are meant for that; you can never expect to be able to compute the limits directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can squeeze as follows:

$$\bigg(\frac{3}{x^{4n}}\bigg)^\frac{1}{n} < \bigg(\frac{3}{x^{4n}}+1\bigg)^\frac{1}{n} < \bigg(\frac{4}{x^{4n}}\bigg)^\frac{1}{n}$$
This is the same as
$$\frac{3^{1 \over n}}{x^{4}} < \bigg(\frac{3}{x^{4n}}+1\bigg)^\frac{1}{n} < \frac{4^{1 \over n}}{x^{4}}$$
Both the left and the right sides of the above go to ${\displaystyle {1 \over x^4}}$ as $n$ goes to infinity, so that has to be the limit.

Answer (score 1):

If $|x|<1$ we have a limit with indeterminate form $\infty^0$. We can then use L'Hospital's by rewriting the limit as $$\lim_{n \to \infty}e^\dfrac{\ln(1+3x^{-4n})}{n}$$ Use L'Hospital's rule on the exponent. I believe after one application of LR we have the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-12x^{-4n}\ln(x)}{1+3x^{-4n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-12\ln(x)}{x^{4n}+3}$$ Since $|x|<1$ we know $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{4n} = 0$, which means
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-12\ln(x)}{x^{4n}+3} \approx \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-12\ln(x)}{0+3} = -4\ln(x)$$ 
 Hence  $$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{3}{x^{4n}}+1\right)^\frac{1}{n} = e^{-4\ln(x)} \\ = x^{-4} \end{align}$$ With thanks to **kobe** for catching my mistake. It may also be worth noting that, had $|x|>1$ been the case, then  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|x^{4n}\right| = \infty$ so we would have found $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-12\ln(x)}{x^{4n}+3} = 0$$ and hence your limit would have been $e^0 = 1$ which would explain your initial confusion.

Comment: @kobe right you are! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: This is just a suggestion, but perhaps you could also mention for the OP's sake that his limit is $1$ for $|x| \color{red}{>} 1$, so that he sees that his inequality is reversed.

Comment: @kobe That is a good observation; I have included it in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may write, for $0<|x|<1$, as $n \to +\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{3}{x^{4n}}+1\right)^{1/n}&=e^{\large \frac1n \log \left(\frac{3}{x^{4n}}+1\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\large \frac1n \log \left(\frac{3}{x^{4n}}\right)+\large \frac1n \log \left(1+\frac{x^{4n}}3\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\large \frac1n \log 3 -\frac1n\log (x^{4n})+\frac1{3n} x^{4n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\large -4\log x+\frac1n \left(\log 3+\frac1{3} x^{4n}\right)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}\\\\
&=\frac1{x^4}e^{\large \frac1n \left(\log 3+\frac1{3} x^{4n}\right)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}\\\\
& \to \frac1{x^4}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\ln(3y^n+1)}{n}=\dfrac{\ln 3+n\ln y + \ln(1+\frac{1}{3y^n})}{n}\to \ln y, n \to \infty\Rightarrow f_n(x) \to y = \dfrac{1}{x^4}$